# Find the TITLE of current webpage open in WebEngine [[JAVAFX]]

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I am coding a Web Browser based on Javafx. I want to fetch the **TITLE** of webpages currently open in the WebEngine.
Thankyou :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the document is loaded you can use the DOM API to find the title. (I generally dislike the DOM API, but here's how you'd do this.)

```
private String getTitle(WebEngine webEngine) {
    Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
    NodeList heads = doc.getElementsByTagName("head");
    String titleText = webEngine.getLocation() ; // use location if page does not define a title
    if (heads.getLength() > 0) {
        Element head = (Element)heads.item(0);
        NodeList titles = head.getElementsByTagName("title");
        if (titles.getLength() > 0) {
            Node title = titles.item(0);
            titleText = title.getTextContent();
        }
    }
    return titleText ;
}
```

Comment: I'am a newbie to JAVAfx while implementing this I am getting errors `error: incompatible types: org.w3c.dom.Document cannot be converted to sun.plugin.dom.core.Document` and `error: incompatible types: org.w3c.dom.Node cannot be converted to sun.plugin.dom.core.Node` @James_D

Comment: You have the wrong imports. Make sure you are importing the correct classes for the return types of the methods you are calling (i.e. you need the `org.w3c.dom` imports, not the private `sun.plugin` classes).

Comment: I am not able to find any `org.w3c.dom` imports for `Node title = titles.item(0);` and `Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();  It would be grateful if you provide me exact imports

Comment: According to the error message, you must have `import sun.plugin.dom.core.Document;` in your code.  It should be `import org.w3c.dom.Document;`. Similarly for `Node`.

Comment: I have imported `import org.w3c.dom.Document;` and `import org.w3c.dom.Node;` but why Netbeans is not able to find this import, It is giving an hint `cannot find symbol`

Comment: It still gives the error message after you include the `org.w3c.dom.*` imports?

Comment: No now its not showing any hint over there but it is showing an exclamation mark(`type of item(int) is erroneous`) in front of line `Element head = (Element)heads.item(0);`. Why so ?

Comment: Also, be aware, `getDocument()` can return null.

Answer (score 5):

A mutch better and nice way is just use the [WebEngine.getTitle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getTitle--)

Here is an example how to use it:

```
stage.titleProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().titleProperty());
```

Comment: I don't know why, in many websites, I'm obtaining `null` when the website clearly has a title.

Comment: @pupeno that's probably because you access the title before it's available. You should register a listener to the property. Or better like my example bind to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different implementation of @James_D excellent answer (little less verbose, little more Java 8 style):

```
private String getTitle(WebEngine webEngine) {
    Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
    NodeList heads = doc.getElementsByTagName("head");
    String titleText = webEngine.getLocation(); // use location if page does not define a title
    return getFirstElement(heads)
            .map(h -> h.getElementsByTagName("title"))
            .flatMap(this::getFirstElement)
            .map(Node::getTextContent).orElse(titleText);
}

private Optional<Element> getFirstElement(NodeList nodeList) {
    if (nodeList.getLength() > 0 && nodeList.item(0) instanceof Element) {
        return Optional.of((Element) nodeList.item(0));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```